# What's the point of referencing a JavaScript file in html if you can just use the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

This is less of a problem and more of a general question, unless you're using a 3rd party JS file, what's the point of creating and referencing a JS file using the  tag if you can just directly write the code using the regular  tag?

Comment: Separation of concerns, modularity, easier editing (and generally better IDE support).

Comment: Also here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223918/is-it-better-to-put-the-js-code-on-the-html-file-or-in-an-external-file

Comment: Who downvote this? please tell me why?

Comment: @Liam okay, thanks!

Comment: @ikhvjs It's probably because there are similar questions to this that already have answers

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons for putting it in its own file:

- You can reuse the JavaScript with another HTML file.
- You don't have to worry about writing the text `</script>` in your JavaScript code inside a comment or string and having it end your code (because it does that when it's embedded in a `script` tag in HTML).
- In source control, changes to the HTML and JavaScript show up in their relevant files rather than everything changing the "HTML".
- They can be cached separately, so changes to one don't invalidate the cache for the other.
- (In larger teams) Different people can work on the HTML than on the JavaScript.

...and of course, these days, a `script` tag is only **one** way that a JavaScript file gets loaded and used by the browser. Another is that it's referenced via an `import`, not directly by a `script` tag.